# Converting a js 'classic' function to an optimized immutable one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking for a way to convert this classic js function to an immutable one for use in a useState component. It checks if the id of an item   is within an array, if it is, it removes it,
else it adds it.

Classic function:

```
   const addOrRemove = (array, item) => {
      array.indexOf(item) === -1 ? array.push(item) : array.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
```

React function:

```
array.indexOf(item) === -1 ? setArray(array=>[...array, item]) : setArray(array.filter(arrayitem=>arrayitem.id !== item.id)
```

Few questions: is it correct? i.e. does it achieve to not mutate state? can it be optimized ? is there a way to do it better a whole different way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you sure you correctly implemented the same logic in the react function? this part `.filter(item=>item.id !item.id` doesn't look good

Comment: [How to update arrays in state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) reference

Comment: @ Diego D was a typo sorry. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your existing function, you are using two methods which mutate the array in-place:

```js
const addOrRemove = (array, item) => {
  array.indexOf(item) === -1
    ? array.push(item)
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^
    //      mutates array
    : array.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1);
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //      mutates array

  // Nothing (undefined) is returned
};
```

This prevents the function from being [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), and is against one of the primary rules of state in React: [Do not modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

Instead, you can create a **new** array which is a shallow copy of the existing array, then mutate the copy and return it:

```js
const addOrRemove = (array, item) => {
  const copy = [...array];

  copy.indexOf(item) === -1
    ? copy.push(item)
    : copy.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1);

  return copy; /*
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  returns a new array */
};
```

Then, you can use it to update your state (without mutating it) like this:

> This example uses the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form of the argument provided to the setter function returned by the `useState` hook:

```js
setArray(array => addOrRemove(array, item));
```

Answer (score 1):

The converted "React function" has a **naming** problem, namely the new `item` supposed to pass in collide with the every iteration of items inside `filter` function:

```
filter(item=> item.id !== item.id)
```

This is bound to return an empty list, since `item.id !== item.id` will always be `false`. Unless you named the new item to something else.

And stick the conditional statement in one-liner makes it hard to read, try this:

```
function handleAddOrRemove(newItem) {
  const newItemExistInArray = array.indexOf(newItem);

  if(newItemExistInArray) { // -1, 0 is evaluated to false, so this is when item exist
    setArray(array.filter(item=> item.id !== newItem.id);
    return;
  }

  setArray(array => [...array, newItem]);
}
```